# How to find the length of integer?

Tags: python, integer

How to find the length of integer? Like if I have variable `A` as below:

```
A = 1000;
```

Then it should return `4` as the length of that integer.

Comment: There shouldn't contain semicolon, isn't it?

Comment: Why do you ask and self answer a question that has already been asked so many times and has so many answers on SO??

Comment: Integers don't have a length, despite that the old duplicate question entertained the idea. Numbers are not the same thing as their *textual representation*. It is an important and key skill for programmers to distinguish things in themselves from their representations.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille self-answering questions is permitted and historically encouraged as a way to share knowledge. However, in this case it doesn't accomplish anything.

Comment: @KarlKnechtelThat was my point. About your other comment, I totally agree -  and the sad thing is that I found the duplicate by googling "number of digits of an int".

Answer (score 2):

you can do yhis thing by **converting Integer into String ** and you can easily find length of String very easily in python by using `len()` function;

```
A = 10000;
length = len(str(A));
```

Answer (score 0):

Mathematically it can be done with log10() and proper rounding, but easier with recursion

```
def num2length(x, len=0):
    if x < 10:
        return len+1
    return num2length(x/10, len+1)
    
print(num2length(1000))
```